# What is the best way to implement belongs to many logic in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For example I have model Match and model Player. What I want is for Player to be able to participate in many matches.

So it should look smth like this:

```
@match_first = Match.first
@match_last  = Match.last

@match_first.players
#player1, player3, player4
@match_last.players
#player1, player4, player5
```

Both matches can have same players simultanously.

Comment: Look like the association you want is n-n, maybe this will help you - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Match model:

```
  has_many: :players, through: :appearances
```

In your Player model:

```
  has_many: :matches, through: :appearances
```

```
class Appearance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :match
  belongs_to :player
```

You could have extra attributes on appearance like 'goals_scored'.  The through model doesn't have to be called Appearance...  it could be Attendance or MatchPlayer or PlayerMatch, but you can see that the last two names are constraining, because out of this association you can also see all the matches a player appeared in.

Answer (score 1):

Rails provides two ways to accomplish the many-to-many relationship. The first, which @zoot's answer describes, is `has_many :through`. This is a great option if the relationship is a Model in its own right (i.e., needs additional attributes or validations).

If the relationship between the two entities is direct such that you don't really need a third model, you can use the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.

In your Match model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :players
```

In your Player model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :matches
```

When you use `has_and_belongs_to_many` you do need to create a join table that holds the relationship. The migration for that (assuming a relatively recent version of Rails) might look like:

```
class CreateJoinTableMatchesPlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :matches_players, :users do |t|
      t.index [:match_id, :player_id], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

There's a section in the [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) guide that talks about how to choose between the two approaches.

Comment: On of the biggest limits with habtm is that you can't actually fetch any additional columns from the join table so you need to rename the table and add a primary key and convert it to `has_many through:` if you ever want to store any additional data like the number of points that a particular player scored in a game.

Comment: No doubt; if I was doing the Player/Match case I’d probably go with the ``has_many through`` approach, but I wanted to ensure they knew there were options.